# Make Terminal recognize PageUp and PageDown when remapped to different keys

Tags: linux, linux-terminal

I understand Terminal by default doesn't support <kbd>PgDn</kbd> and <kbd>PgUp</kbd>. I do not have <kbd>PgDn</kbd> and <kbd>PgUp</kbd> on my keyboard, but have them remapped to different keys currently and therefore <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> doesn't work. I have also tried <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>. How can I make Terminal recognize my remapped paging keys?

Comment: Which terminal doesn't support pgdn/pgup?

Comment: I'm sure it supports.

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: I'm confused. You're looking for a Linux terminal app that supports PgDn and PgUp because you don't have PgDn and PgUp keys on your keyboard? Getting a new terminal app isn't going to magically add physical keys to your keyboard. I'm doubtful that's what you meant, so perhaps you could clarify your question? But keep in mind that asking for software recommendations is [off topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @8bittree you can reassign the location of PgDn and PgUp on your keyboard like I have done but then shift+PgDn and shift+PgUp don't work on the new assigned locations.

Comment: Did you try to use Fn+Up(Down) arrow instead of Page Up(Down)? Many times it works.

Comment: @Hastur yes it doesn't work

Comment: You can use Scroll Lock, but it's not configured by default in Ubuntu. You can fix it with this procedure: https://linuxtechie.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/getting-scroll-lock-to-work-in-ubuntu/

Comment: @cscracker how does scroll lock relate to PgDn and PgUp.

Comment: @William Scroll lock, when turned on, allows you to use the arrows and page up/down buttons to scroll through the buffer. It's what we had before shift+pgup/pgdn was created. It's a toggle into a scrolling mode, which is why it's called Scroll Lock. Linux and most Unices support this functionality but some modern ones (Ubuntu) don't map the key by default. If you do map the key yourself, it'll work.

Comment: Oh, so questions with a bounty can't be closed, that's convenient. Software recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: @DanielB I have no desire for a piece of software I would like to do this natively in fact.

Comment: So update your question. Thoroughly. Explain what you want. Explain you remapped keys or whatever. Include all the scattered information from the comments. There's a lot of them so they won't be visible by default!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(comment: you've found XKB!  congratulations, it's a hell of a rabbit hole to fall down.  note your solution will get blown away the next time ubuntu's xkb-data package updates that file, and will affect any other keyboards you plug in that use the same configuration.)

XKB follows a model called RMLVO -- Rules, Model, Layout, Variant, Options.  Your solution alters a system Model file, but a better solution would be to find or create an Option to add your overrides.  (`evdev` is the default Rule for most distributions, and most external keyboards will use a `pc` model, though laptop internal models may have specific variations that are already close to your usecase.  A standard US QWERTY keyboard will use the `us` layout with no variant, although you might choose the `intl` or `altgr-intl` variants if you work with other languages.)

Options are specific overrides to the basic functionality.  If you want to turn off CapsLock because that key just sucks, there's already an option for that (`caps:none`), or you can set it to be an extra Escape key instead (`caps:escape`).  You can see the specific overrides in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/caps`; each stanza is a different option you can turn on at runtime.

If you do `setxkbmap -print` you should get a list of your current XKB setup:

```
$ setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"};
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Create your override file:

```
$ mkdir -p .config/xkb/symbols
$ touch .config/xkb/symbols/pgupdown
```

Now edit the new file with your favorite editor and throw in the following:

```
// mapping PgUp and PgDown to other keys
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "rwinmenu" {
    key <RWIN> { [ Prior     ]   };
    key <MENU> { [ Next      ]   };
};

// same but switched
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "menurwin" {
    key <MENU> { [ Prior     ]   };
    key <RWIN> { [ Next      ]   };
};
```

Now create a base keymap:

```
$ setxkbmap -print > ~/.config/xkb/mymap
```

Edit that file, and add your new option into the symbols list in the format `+optionfile(function)`:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete" };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"};
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)+pgupdown(rwinmenu)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

If you decide later that you prefer PgUp on the Menu key instead, just replace `rwinmenu` with `menurwin` there and you're good to go.

Now you can load that file with `xkbcomp`:

```
$ xkbcomp -I$HOME/.config/xkb $HOME/.config/xkb/mymap $DISPLAY
```

Launch `xev` (from the `x11-utils` package) and press keys to make sure the changes are loaded:

```
# sed to scrape out non-kbd events; xev is pretty spammy
$ xev | sed -ne '/^KeyPress/,/^$/p'
```

If you've gotten everything in the right places, your Menu key should be sending Next events, and the Win_R key sending Prior.  If that works, you can add the above `xkbcomp` command to your `.xinitrc` or `.xprofile` so it runs when you log in or start X.

... unless you're running Gnome. (and/or possibly KDE.)  Then we get to go further down the rabbit hole, and figure out how to incorporate this new option into system files so the DEs can pick it up as a standard option.  Essentially, that will involve

1. placing your option file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` (this is why `pgupdown` was a good option choice, as there's not a preexisting symbol file with that name)
2. and then adding lines in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev*` (to map the `optionsfile:function` format of the commandline to the `+optionsfile(function)` used by `xkbcomp`)
3. and finally setting the DE to use your preferred layout and options.

Step 2: If you need to go this route, you might need to perform step 2 again after any xkb-related upgrades.

```
# in /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev
# find the line that starts "! option = symbols" and add new lines:
  pgupdown:rwinmenu = +pgupdown(rwinmenu)
  pgupdown:menurwin = +pgupdown(menurwin)

# in /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst
# find the line that starts "! option" and add a new line:
  pgupdown:rwinmenu          PgUp on RWin, PgDown on Menu
  pgupdown:menurwin          PgUp on Menu, PgDown on RWin

# in /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml
# .... ummm .... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  .... sorry! ....
```

Step 3: check to see if `localectl` is available on your system.  `localectl` can configure the virtual console keyboards as well as setting up a system-default X11 keyboard.  Since both options are set up in the rules files, you can use either `rwinmenu` or `menurwin` in these commands.

```
$ localectl set-x11-keymap us pc "" pgupdown:rwinmenu
#  format               [layout] [model] [variant] [option1,...,optionN]
```

For Gnome, you'll need to use `dconf-editor` or `gsettings`:

```
# set layout/variant
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us')]"

# set options
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['pgupdown:rwinmenu']"
```

Another option for Gnome might be to disable its keyboard settings; this should allow either the localectl option or the user-config option to remain in effect:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false
```

**Troubleshooting:** If your changes don't seem to be getting picked up and you're sure you've gotten file formatting right, delete any `*.xkm` files from `/var/lib/xkb/`.  These are cached precompiled keymaps and may be getting in your way.

Resources:

- http://madduck.net/docs/extending-xkb/
- http://apps.jcns.fz-juelich.de/doku/sc/xkbmap
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66624/where-is-xkb-getting-its-configuration
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/451945/permanently-set-keyboard-layout-options-with-setxkbmap-in-gnome-unity

Comment: So I actually ended up using key <RALT> for Prior instead do you mind updating before I post bounty.

Comment: I notice your account is unregistered. Your answers are *great* so go get an account. Ask for a merger from contact us if anything goes  odd.

Comment: I created an account on Super User just to upvote this question! It was extremely useful for me. In my case I was trying to remap the print screen key to the left super key in GNOME, and none of the various ways to do this that I could find (e.g. xmodmap) seemed quite right. This answer had the exact right strategy! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the keys at /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc seems to work I could not get the other answer above to work.  Then you use the new keys with the shift button.

```
key <RWIN> {    [ Prior     ]   };
key <MENU> {    [ Next          ]   };
```

Answer (score 0):

The default Ubuntu terminal does support pgup and pgdn, the shortcuts are [shift]+pgup and [shift]+pgdn. Most other terminals you try will have the exact same shortcuts, mostly because pgup and pgdn is already taken by bash for certain things, so you can't really use it.

edit: if you need to remap your pgup and pgdn keys, you can follow this answer on askubuntu for linux:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices/24930#24930

Comment: That would still need Page Up and Page Down keys. (But indeed the question's title was quite bad.)

Comment: oh ok, cool. If you need to remap commands you can follow the advice in this answer. http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices/24930#24930

Comment: If that can be made to work with, for example, Shift then I guess you should [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1136810/edit) your answer? (Note that I'm not the question asker...)

Comment: I tried remapping the keys and they do not register with their new location.