# xkb - Why i get ŭ instead of ù on linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout

I am Italian and I use an English keyboard that has less keys so there are combination with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and the letter like <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to get `ì`.

So to improve the layout I made a few changes to have the most used accents on aioue. The problem that in my layout everything I put for the `u` key is ignored.

I am using the "English (US, international AltGr Unicode combining)" layout (which is a little bit extended version of the "English (US, international with dead keys)" layout) and this is my edited `us` file (I know at every update I have to reconfigure but I have a backup but until I don't understand where the problem is I prefer to continue that way) http://pastebin.com/X79JJjx7

I have no idea how to debug and understand why I get a `ŭ` with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> (I think it's `ubreve` on xkb syntax) instead of `ù` (it's `ugrave` on xkb syntax).
Does anyone have any suggestion to help me fix this very annoying problem? As a temporary fix I'm using my text editor's autofix feature, but it is not the right way, of course, and also very very disappointing.

Comment: i use the `altgr-intl` variant of the `us` with the `compose:menu` option.  in this setup, `AltGr+u` gets `ú` but `Compose+u+u` gets `ŭ`.  do you have a Compose key already, or a Menu or other key you could use as that?  if you can, add the result of `setxkbmap -print` to your question, and list what distribution and GUI (Gnome, KDE, other) you're using.

Comment: I have the compose button but is very annoying and I prefer a solution more simple like two keys to press.

Comment: oh! that `altgr-intl` has a deadkey on left-paren: `AltGr+(, u` gets your `ŭ`.  it's `dead_breve` in your pastebin file.

Comment: see my answer [on making small customizations to XKB layouts](http://superuser.com/a/1168603/685512).  the customization you're looking for is the same basic process: you create an option file that will override specific keys in the default layout, then you load that option over the layout (say, at login, if configured per-user).  see `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/epo` for examples of partial override stanzas showing `ubreve` and `Ubreve`; your customization option would probably look a lot like those.

Comment: I find the problem, my xkb config file is http://pastebin.com/UWJqHp9S. After the mention of epo I looked in the settings and saw `epo(qwerty)`. That was forced in KDE from a settings because I have also the esperanto layout but never considered that was forcing the char. DIsabled and now is working perfect! Thanks for the help!