# How to customize user keyboard layout(on Fedora 24)

Tags: linux, keyboard, fedora, keyboard-layout, xkb

I want to add symbols to the third level(`AtlGr+<key>`) of my keyboard layout(which is `French (Canada)`). I've written an xkb symbols snippet:

```
default  partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "greek_letters" {
    name[Group1] = "French (Canada) with greek_letters"

    include "French (Canada)"

    key <AC01>  { [         a,          A,          U3B1]   };
    key <AC02>  { [         s,          S,          U3C3]   };
    key <AC09>  { [         l,          L,          U3BB ]  };

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```

And now I'd like to incorporate it to my layout, but ideally only locally, for my user(I don't want to contaminate system files).

Is that doable?

Otherwise, what's the simplest way to do what I want to do?

Thanks!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1133476/make-terminal-recognize-pageup-and-pagedown-when-remapped-to-different-keys/1168603#1168603

Comment: for your use case i wouldn't use the `include` statements, just load up the system layouts closest to what you want and add your user-specific options after to override specific keys.

Comment: How would I do that?