# How do I install a new custom keymapping in XKB?

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg, keymap, xkb

I am attempting to install a custom symbols file in my keyboard mapping in XKB, as [found here](https://superuser.com/questions/1133476/make-terminal-recognize-pageup-and-pagedown-when-remapped-to-different-keys/1168603#1168603).  I would like to overwrite how the `J` key is handled (the first step in emulating a numpad, but for now I am simply applying the same mapping as found in the `us` symbols file). However, at the step where I load the file using `xkbcomp`, I get an error.  Please find the error state and file contents below:

The map, which was created by modifying the output of `setxkbmap -print`, adding "`+altkeypad_symbols(altkeypad)`" to the end of the `xkb_symbols` include statement.

```
~$ cat .xkb/altkeypad_map 
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+us:2+inet(evdev)+altkeypad_symbols(altkeypad)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

The custom symbols file, a simple toy case of "remapping" the `J` key to its normal function.

```
~$ cat .xkb/symbols/altkeypad_symbols 
// Emulate the keypad using {j k l u i o 7 8 9} as KP_{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}

default partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "altkeypad" {
    key <AC07> {        [         j,    J               ]       };
}
```

Attempting to install the new map, yielding an error, made increasingly odd given the fact that the symbol "J" appears on line 5 of the file, not line 7.

```
~$ xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb $HOME/.xkb/altkeypad_map $DISPLAY
syntax error: line 7 of altkeypad_symbols
last scanned symbol is: J
Error:            Error interpreting include file "altkeypad_symbols"
                  Exiting
                  Abandoning symbols file "(null)"
Error:            success in unknown
                  Couldn't write keyboard description to :0
```

As far as I know, I've very closely matched the syntax of other custom symbols mapping.  Any help resolving the error would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is missing a semi colon there

```
// Emulate the keypad using {j k l u i o 7 8 9} as KP_{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}

default partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "altkeypad" {
    key <AC07> {        [         j,    J               ]       };
}; <<----- HERE!
```